# Where do the "classical lattices" come from?

Tags: integer-lattices, packing-problem, vector-lattices, reductive-groups

I am trying to understand sphere packing problems, and it seems well-known that lattices can be only of certain kinds: the classical types (e.g. $A_n, B_n$, etc.) or the exceptional types (e.g. $E_8$).

Where can I find these lattices explained? Do they arise naturally?

(Note that I know nothing about lattices, but I heard they appear as root systems of Lie groups, or something of this kind)

Comment: I never heard about the classical or exceptional lattices you mentioned. It seems likely to me that the tag 'lattices-order' is inadequate here. There are other lattices tags, such as 'integer-lattices', 'vector-lattices' and perhaps some more; maybe you should consult these tag infos to check if some of them fits better in your post.

Comment: @amrsa Thanks for the comment, I edited accordingly.